# How to use langchain load_evaluator() with local llm?

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I try to use langchain load_evaluator() with local LLM Ollama. But I don't understand which model I should use.

```
from langchain.evaluation import load_evaluator
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOllama
from langchain.llms import Ollama
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
```

```
#This is work
evaluator = load_evaluator("labeled_score_string", llm=ChatOllama(model="llama2"))
evaluator = load_evaluator("pairwise_string",  llm=Ollama(model="llama2"))
```

```
#This is not
evaluator = load_evaluator("pairwise_embedding_distance",  llm=HuggingFaceEmbeddings())
evaluator = load_evaluator("pairwise_embedding_distance",  llm=Ollama(model="llama2"))
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community! I think your question is a bit broad to be well-received on the site. Can you add more details? What exactly is not working? Are there any error messages? Does it work with other LLMs rather than Ollama?